# What amperage fuse for Trane XL-80 gas furnace?

Tags: furnace

I would think this would be something that could easily be Googled, but I've tried and can't find it.

We have a Trane XL-80 gas furnance and when we had an insulation guy checking out the furnace, he remarked that the furnace switch in our furnace closet should really be an SSU switch with a fuse in it. I forgot to ask him what amperage fuse to use. Anyone know?

Comment: Modern furnaces on suitable breakers don't need fused disconnects. That's old-school. What's your breaker and wiring situation?

Comment: The guy's company does insulation but also installs furnaces. We showed him the furnace closet because we were asking him if it was okay that there was a gap in the ceiling of the closet leading into the attic. He said that everything looked proper except that he recommended the SSU switch.

Comment: Can you take photos of the informational label (s) on the furnace?  It may be behind an access panel.

Comment: I had that same furnace in my previous home. It was installed with a typical residential light switch in a box mounted to the chassis. NM-B ran through flex conduit from the ceiling.

Comment: So the answer is that the question is invalid, and you should let furnace guys give you furnace advice. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The switch is based on the load, but since the furnace is a dedicated circuit what size breaker is the unit on? I would guess a 15 amp but I haven't seen a gas furnace with anything larger than a 20 amp the switch must have a labeled on /off position but other than that a standard switch is fine.